# Max, Min and Step attributes

Tags: html, css, attributes

Max, Min and  Step attributes are not recognized by `Notepad++`. The are written in black when they are supposed to be red as an attribute. Is that possible that Notepad doesn't know these attributes?

Try to yourself.

```html
<form action="">
 Quantity (between 0 and 100):
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="100" step="10" value="30" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes...it's possible. Next question?

Comment: You need later version of [notepad++](https://www.google.com/search?q=notepad%2B%2B+html5&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @Marin, I have added latest software link in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36522223/5832518) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old versions won't support these attributes.

Download latest version from [notepad-plus-plus.org](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or click below link to download.

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/

Please see the difference of the attribute coloring between two versions of Notepad++ :

#### **Before installation:**

[image: notepadd ++ 5.9]

#### **After installation:**

[image: notepad ++ 6.9]

Comment: I installed the latest version from the link you provided and it is till blacked out for me.

Comment: *it is still blacked out

Comment: @rgolden,  set Language -> H -> HTML from notepad++ menu

Comment: Yeah, it's still blacked out. Oddly enough though, when I actually run the site it seems to be recognizing the values. They're just not displayed in red in the code. So, I guess it's not really a problem...